# How to resample a TimeSeries in pandas with a fill_value?

Tags: python, pandas, time-series, resampling

I have a `TimeSeries` of integers that I would like to downsample using `resample()`. The problem is that I have some periods with missing data that are converted to `NaN`. Since pandas does not support [Integer NA values](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/gotchas.html) the integers are converted to floats.

Is it possible to resample a `TimeSeries` using a `fill_value` for missing data like I can with `reindex(fill_value=0)`? I don't want my integers cast into floats.

```
>>> dates = (datetime(2013, 1, 1), datetime(2013,1,2), datetime(2013,3,1))
>>> s = Series([1,2,4],index=dates)
>>> s
2013-01-01    1
2013-01-02    2
2013-03-01    4
dtype: int64
>>> s.resample('M', how='sum')
2013-01-31     3
2013-02-28   NaN
2013-03-31     4
Freq: M, dtype: float64

# Desired output (doesn't work)
>>> s.resample('M', how='sum', fill_value=0)
2013-01-31     3
2013-02-28     0
2013-03-31     4
Freq: M, dtype: int64
```

Comment: It's so strange that your third value is 4 (the one indexed as 2013-03-01).

Comment: @waitingkuo You're right. Fixed copy-and-paste typo.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can define your own function to avoid `NaN`

```
In [36]: def _sum(x):
   ....:     if len(x) == 0: return 0
   ....:     else: return sum(x)
   ....:     

In [37]: s.resample('M', how=_sum)
Out[37]: 
2013-01-31    3   
2013-02-28    0   
2013-03-31    3   
Freq: M, dtype: int64
```

Comment: Sure, but that just does a cast from int to float and then back to int. I don't want to loose any precision by casting ints to floats.

Comment: I think there's no precision issue while converting int to float.

Comment: While you are concerning the casting issue, I add another method hope it might help.

Comment: I don't think that's true: `int(float(max_int)) == max_int` where `max_int = np.iinfo(np.int64).max` returns `False`

Comment: `np.int64(np.float64(max_int)) == max_int` is also `False`

Comment: The second method works. I'll go ahead and accept it when you edit your answer.

Comment: With pandas 0.18.0, there is now an easier and faster way to do this: `s.resample('M').sum().fillna(0)`